# How to send data from a C program to a websocket using libwebsockets without using the callback function?

Tags: c, libwebsockets

For a project we're using the libwebsockets to communicate to a webserver. The problem is that we can only send data from the C program to the webserver when we received data, and we can't send data at any moment we want to. Is there any way to send data without receiving data using the libwebsockets?

Answer (score 0):

Generally to send something you call libwebsocket_callback_on_writable(context, wsi) and then send it in the callback.